# Android : Facing issue while passing data from fragment to other fragment

Tags: android, android-bundle

This might be a very simple issue. But I'am getting difficulty to find the problem where i have done.

I'am passing data from One fragment to other fragment.

This is my code which i have written to pass the data.

```
Fragment fr = new ProjectFragment();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putString("project_id", pro.p_id);
          fr.setArguments(args);
```

Receiving code.

```
String project_id = getArguments().getString("project_id");
```

I'am getting null value in project_id. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Just check is this `pro.p_id` null???

Comment: I got the value. I also printed the args.

Comment: You have to commit this Fragment into FragmentTransaction.

Comment: @user3764346 Show your Fragment transaction code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta No i have not written any code for fragment transaction

Comment: @user3764346 Is your ProjectFragment is calling have you checked that? And if yes then your pro.p_id will be null.